# how to recover data from drive which has data but not showing

Tags: windows-xp

im using laptop with windows xp OS..my D: drive is infected with virus..its not displaying the data but properties show a data of 9gb present in the drive.i tried show hidden files and folders also...i also tried *.* by typing it in search box but it didn't work..it worked well with windows8.but my OS is Windows XP..
please tell me a way to recover the data.

Comment: We don't email answers - we answer here so *others* may benefit. In addition, so that we don't replicate your efforts, it might help to say what you have done, and have considered doing so far, and giving as much details as possible to what exactly caused this

Answer (score 0):

Download, burn and boot from a rescue disc such as http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage (which runs Linux but it doesn't matter) and see if it can see your data.  If so, you can back them up to another drive before running an anti-virus on it.

AVG makes a downloadable boot disc for cleaning systems as well, very handy and free @ http://www.avg.com/ca-en/avg-rescue-cd-download